# GCP AI platform prediction request from Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a model on GCP AI Platform and can successfully request for prediction from my Jupyter Notebook. However, I need to to perform request from my Flutter application and can't seem to find to a way to do so.

The following code is the one working fine on the notebook:

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from googleapiclient import discovery

endpoint = 'https://australia-southeast1-ml.googleapis.com'
client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=endpoint)
ml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', client_options=client_options)

request_body = { 'instances': [image_content] }
request = ml.projects().predict(
    name='projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/models/[MODEL_NAME]/versions/version1/',
    body=request_body)

response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

Is there a way to convert this python code to dart to be used in my Flutter application ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are Dart packages available to connect with the GCP AI Platform.

- The AI Platform Training & Prediction API for Dart can be found at the following [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/ml.v1/ml.v1-library.html). You can use the suitable class to request predictions.
- Other available Google Cloud APIs for Dart are available at this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis). You can find an example of the Dart Storage API in the “Example” section for your reference.

Comment: Yes but those packages are badly documented and I could not implement the above function. I was expecting if someone has actually tried to do so and has a working example, as in my case, the functions in the packages were insufficient to get the output. Thanks for pointing out the packages though.